# JAVA.Cambio de valor al entrar en un método.Cifraje

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente main:

```
 public class main {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


 String cleartext = "hola";

 System.out.println(cleartext+" <- Texto normal");
 Cifrar c = new Cifrar();
 System.out.println(c.encrypt(cleartext.getBytes())+" <- este es el texto 
 encriptado");
 System.out.println(c.decrypt(c.encrypt(cleartext.getBytes()))+" <-Texto 
 desencriptado");
```

Y este es mi clase a la que llamo desde el main:

```
public  class Cifrar {

// Definición del tipo de algoritmo a utilizar (AES, DES, RSA)
private final static String alg = "AES";
private final static int keyLength=128;
private final static int ivLength=128;
private final static String cI =  "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
private byte [] iv;
private byte[] aesKeyBytes;
private IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec;


public Cifrar() throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance(alg);
    keyGen.init(keyLength, new SecureRandom());
    SecretKey aesKey = keyGen.generateKey();
    aesKeyBytes = aesKey.getEncoded();
    iv = SecureRandom.getSeed(ivLength / 8);
    ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

}


 public Cifrar(byte[]aesKeyBytesQuemePasan, IvParameterSpec ivspecquemePasan) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {


    aesKeyBytes = aesKeyBytesQuemePasan;
    ivParameterSpec = ivspecquemePasan;

}

public void setAesKeyBytes(byte[] aesKeyBytes) {
    this.aesKeyBytes = aesKeyBytes;
}

public void setIv(byte[] iv) {
    this.iv = iv;
}  

public byte[] encrypt(byte[] cleartext) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cI);
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(aesKeyBytes, alg);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(cleartext);
    return encrypted;
}

public byte[] decrypt( byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(encrypted+" <- entra algo diferente");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cI);
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(aesKeyBytes, alg);
    System.out.println(encrypted + "  aqui despues viene el fallo");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivParameterSpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    return decrypted;
}

}
```

Mi duda es que no entiendo que sucede

```
hola <- Texto normal
[B@1f107db9 <- este es el texto encriptado
[B@73ae0c9d <- entra algo diferente
[B@27be52c0 <-Texto desencriptado
```

Además, solamente se generán casi siempre la misma clave.

A ver si me podeis ayudar de porque entra un encryt diferente al metodo descifrar.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

No estas imprimiendo el contenido del array, si no un identificador que java genera para los arrays (realmente es el toString() de Array).

Arrays.toString() puede ayudar, pero como realmente son datos binarios, seguro que hay valores que no se corresponden con caracteres imprimibles. Necesitas convertir primero el char[] a un String con su representacion hexadecimal. Usa esto:

```
private final static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

Ya con esa funcion:

```
char[] cbytes = c.encrypt(cleartext.getBytes());
String chex = bytesToHex(cbytes);
System.out.println(chex+" <- este es el texto encriptado");
```